# google spreadsheet script new google.maps.places.Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, maps, spreadsheet

I would like to be able to autofill county state country when the user enters a city in a spreadsheet under City. I was thinking to use google.maps.places.Autocomplete. I can't figure out a way to do it. 
Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please add what you have tried..

Comment: I tried to implement without success the ideas found in this documentation.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete